# How to synchronize a byte sent to the TXD line with the DTR signal in Python

Tags: serial-port, driver, pyserial

I would like to perfectly synchronize each byte sent to the TXD line of my native RS232 port with a high level of the DTR line in Python. I know my RS232 can do it because I have a compiled software which succeeds to do it very precisely each time (see picture attached). Bits are sent at 9600 baud, so DTR signal must be high during 1ms (10 bits sent for 1 data byte).

I currently succeed to enable and disable DTR signal by software with the setDTR() function of the pyserial library but it is not accurate and I often lost answers of my DCE after sending a TXD byte. I need to find how to configure my com port with Python to automatically do it at a lower level (driver level I guess).

Maybe someone can help me ?

Thanks for reading me.

[TXD_DTR_synchronization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWUGG.png)

Comment: "*with the setDTR() function of the pyserial library but it is not accurate*" - Because a userspace process is not synchronized with I/O (unless you try specific actions). What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is best not to use devices that require such special control from an OS(Windows) that cannot perform strict real-time control. It seems reasonable to build a dedicated control program in C or Assembler language on some small MCU chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally succeeded to make an accurate control of the DTR line on Windows. I use the micros() function of this library :

[GS_timing](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_PyTime)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).